# my father or Father?

Tags: single-word-requests

In the following sentence, which one is more common?

> I asked my mother, "Where is my father?"

Or

> I asked my mother, "Where is Father?"

Comment: Think of it this way, if he were your brother, Joe, instead of your father, you'd have situations where you'd say, "Where is Joe?" and others where you'd say, "Where is my brother."  You use *Father* and *my father* the same way.

Comment: @DanHall - Sorry.  I think you’ve missed my point.

Comment: @DanHall - I think in the contexts where “Father” is a viable option for that person it actually is.  I’m not trying to choose between Joe and a paternal reference.  I’m trying to provide guidance on which  paternal reference to use.

Comment: @DanHall - Ok.  Well, I think you’re still trying to apply my guidance where it wasn’t intended.  That probably means I haven’t stated things as clearly as I’d hoped.  In any event I think I’m finished here for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"My father" clarifies which father you're talking about. In common usage, if you're talking to your mother, you don't need to specify "my father" (vs. your mother's father, who you'd refer to as grandfather).

You could make a case for "my father" if there was a sort of argument and you wanted to emphasize your personal relationship over your mother's relationship with your father, but generally, if the tone is neutral and the relationship between the three of you is typical, use "Father".

Comment: If I don't specify my father, do I use Father or father? Thanks.

Comment: Father, since you're referring to him as a person,

Comment: Just a note, in many families, "Dad" is much more common than "Father".  I think I'd wonder if something was wrong if my daughter asked, "Where's Father" instead of "Where's Dad?"

Comment: There are sometimes ethnic and cultural differences between people who call their male parent "Dad", "Father", "Pop", "Papa", "Pa", and assorted other terms.

Comment: Yes, usage of "Father" vs "Dad" or other terms for a male parent is a question of register, region, and culture.

Comment: In 19th-century English fiction characters sometimes refer to their parent as 'my father' or 'my mother' even when addressing another family member, but no-one would think of doing so today.